# Proof of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n x^2}{(1+x^{2})^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

How to prove that
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^2 \frac{n}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{n+1}}
$$
is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{x^2}
$$ for $\frac{1}{|1+x^{2}|} < 1$?

I have tried using geometric series, but I have a problem with numerator.

Comment: Write down the value of $\sum (1+x^{2})^{-n}$ , differentiate the equation and multiply by $-x/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: $$
\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{x^2 n}{(1 + x^2)^{n+1}} = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{n}{(1 + x^2)^{n}} - \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{n}{(1 + x^2)^{n+1}} = S(x) - F(x)
$$

Consider the following series and its derivative to find $S(x)$ and $F(x)$:
$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{(1 + x^2)^n}
$$